# Blank screen while fetching JSON data from url android

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I am fetching a JSON response from a URL. The URL returns a huge  JSON response. While I get the response the application shows a blank(black) screen. I want to show a `ProgressDialog` while the data loads. But I am unable to think where can I place this dialog box.

Here is my code:

```
    JSONArray myDataItems = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mydataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


      TextView txtTitle;
      TextView txtBody;
     ImageView imgThumbnail;
     HashMap<String, String> map ;
      //URL to get JSON Array
      private static String url = "someurl";
      ProgressDialog pDialog;

     JSONArray newsArray = null;

    private ListAdapter itemsAdapter;
    //Details detail = new Details();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        txtTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        txtBody = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.desc);
        imgThumbnail = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon);
        newsList = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);


        myDataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        usersName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUsersName);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        HostUrl = in.getStringExtra("HostUrl");
        encodedAccountName = in.getStringExtra("EncodedAccountName");
        refreshToken = in.getStringExtra("RefreshToken");
        realm = in.getStringExtra("Realm");

        usersName.setText(in.getStringExtra("UsersName"));

        List<RowItem> rowItems;

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        String registerContet = "someotherurl";

        String items;
        try
        {

            items = new FetchItems().execute(registerContet).get();


            JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(items);
            for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++)
            {
                 JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject(i);

                 String title= menuObject.getString("Title");
                 String description= menuObject.getString("BodyText");
                 String thumbnail= menuObject.getString("ThumbnailPath");
                 String newsUrl = menuObject.getString("Url");
                 String body = menuObject.getString("Body");
                 String newsBigImage = menuObject.getString("ImageBlobUrls");

                    map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    map.put(SOURCETITLE, title);
                    map.put(TITLE, description);
                    map.put(THUMBNAILPATH, thumbnail);
                    map.put(BODY, body);
                    map.put(URL, newsUrl);
                    map.put(IMAGEBLOBURLS,newsBigImage);

                    myNewsList.add(map);


             itemsAdapter = new LazyAdapter(Home.this, myNewsList);
                newsList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

                newsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        HashMap<String, String> myMap = myDataList.get(position);
                        Intent nIntent = new Intent(Home.this,NDetails.class);
                        nIntent.putExtra("Items", myMap);

                        startActivity(nIntent);

                    }
                });
        }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }









    private class FetchItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    HttpResponse response =null;
                    String resultString = "";
                    String myResponseBody = "" ;
                    // Creating HTTP client
                            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            // Creating HTTP Post
                            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                            try 
                            {
                                response = httpClient.execute(request);
                                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200)
                                {
                                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                                    if (entity != null)
                                    {

                                        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                                        myResponseBody = convertToString(inputStream);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                            }
                    return myResponseBody;
                }
@Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    if(pDialog.isShowing())
                    {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }





                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading");
                    pDialog.show();
                }
}
```

LazyAdapter.java

```
    public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public Context myContext;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    public Context mContext;
    public ProgressDialog pDialog;

      public LazyAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) 
      {
            mContext = ctx;
            data=d;
            inflater =LayoutInflater.from(ctx);

            //imageLoader=new ImageLoader();
        }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(com.zevenpooja.attini.R.layout.list_row,null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(com.zevenpooja.attini.R.id.title); // title
        TextView description = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.description); // artist name




        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(Home.SOURCETITLE));

        String mydescription = song.get(Home.TITLE);
        mydescription = mydescription.substring(0, Math.min(mydescription.length(), 50));
        description.setText(mydescription);

        String bitmapUrl = song.get(Home.THUMBNAILPATH);




        Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(song.get(Home.THUMBNAILPATH));



        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
        if(bitmap!=null)
        {

        thumb_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        else
            thumb_image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

      //  ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
      //  imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(Home.THUMBNAILPATH), thumb_image);

        return vi;
    }
    private class OpenHttpConnection extends AsyncTask<String, String, InputStream> 
    {

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             InputStream in = null;
                int response = -1;


                try 
                {

                    URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpConn.connect();
                    response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                    if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
                    {
                        in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return in;
        }

    }
    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) 
    {
          Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream in = null;
            try
            {
                in = new OpenHttpConnection().execute(URL).get();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                in.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ExecutionException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
     }
}
```

How can I resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Post your logcat. In this items = new FetchItems().execute(registerContet).get(); for what **registerContet** stands for?

Answer (score 0):

change your fetchItem class to :

```
 private class FetchItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
 {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
   ProgressDialog dialog;
     @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
    }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpResponse response =null;
            String resultString = "";
            String myResponseBody = "" ;
            // Creating HTTP client
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    // Creating HTTP Post
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                    try 
                    {
                        response = httpClient.execute(request);
                        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200)
                        {
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            if (entity != null)
                            {

                                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                                myResponseBody = convertToString(inputStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    }
            return myResponseBody;
        }
      @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your FetchItems AsyncTask class

start progressDialog in onPreExecute()

```
 @Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle("title");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

and Stop in onPostExecute() method

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
 {
   progressDialog.dismiss(); 
 }
```

Comment: NO i think you have pass context at wrong place create  progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context); in your FetchItems AsyncTask class only and pass context

Comment: I did change it to the way you suggested but it still behaves the same

Comment: it does not show any error. The progress dialog display after the list is displayed. I want it before it is displayed

Comment: try to debug its logical error flow of execution check code line by line